# Best practise to clean up old Spark 1.2.0 application logs?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running Spark 1.2.0. I noticed that I have a bunch of old application logs under `/var/lib/spark/work` that don't seem to get cleaned up. What are best practises for cleaning these up? A cronjob? Looks like newer Spark versions has some kind of cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three SPARK_WORKER_OPTS exists to support the worker application folder cleanup, copied here for further reference from [spark doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts):

- `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled`, default value is false, Enable periodic
  cleanup of worker / application directories. Note that this only
  affects standalone mode, as YARN works differently. Only the
  directories of stopped applications are cleaned up.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.interval`, default is 1800, i.e. 30 minutes, Controls the interval, in seconds, at which the worker cleans up old
  application work dirs on the local machine.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl`, default is 7*24*3600 (7 days), The number of seconds to retain application work directories on each
  worker. This is a Time To Live and should depend on the amount of
  available disk space you have. Application logs and jars are
  downloaded to each application work dir. Over time, the work dirs can
  quickly fill up disk space, especially if you run jobs very
  frequently.